# Parse digits only from mixed character string on arduino

Tags: string, parsing, arduino, indexof, digit

I am using Arduino Uno with Sim900 GSM board. In my code I use the command AT+CGSN to retrieve the IMEI from the chip. This is (in my case) a 15 digit number sequence returned as: 
AT+CGSN

013949150670600

OK

This is received by:

```
void GetID(){
 GPRS.print("");   
  GPRS.println("AT+CGSN");    
  delay(200);    
 {    
  while(!GPRS.available());    
  if(GPRS.available()){    
    while(GPRS.available()){    
      imei_character = GPRS.read();    
      imei_content.concat(imei_character);    
//      delay(20);    
//      imei_content.trim();    
//      delay(20);      
    }
  }
  delay(1500);

} 

}
```

I have used .length() to determine that there are at least 10 whitespaces within the response, which puts the first digit at position 11. I know that to just parse the numbers I can use:

```
 String getGSMid(){  
return imei_content.substring(11, 25);
}
```

or alternatively I can turn off command echo to remove the "AT+CSGN" then use "imei_content.trim();" to remove the leading whitespace and from there use
 return imei_content.substring(0, 15); instead.

What I would prefer through is to look at the response regardless of what it is and find the sequence of digits and extract it based on the fact that it is a digit, to the effect of:

```
    String getGSMid(){         
  return imei_content.substring(imei_content.indexOf('0>='),         imei_content.lastIndexOf('0>='));        
}
```

I am a novice coder, so although I have seen the likes of isdigit(), Regex, Sscanf, I am not sure if any are appropriate for my application. Ideally I would like to avoid adding a library and to keep the code as simple as possible. If I can adapt what I have to make a robust piece of code that will reliably parse the 15 digit id regardless of the return format (I realise that if there are any stray digits returned, which are not part of the ID this may throw things out, this is acceptable). It may be that disabling echo and trimming is the easiest way forward and "reliable enough" - hopefully someone can lead me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the characters of your `imei_content` string looking for the start and end of a group of digits, like this:

```
// Find the index of the first digit
int startPos = 0;
do
{
    if (isdigit(imei_content.charAt(startPos))
        break;
}
while (++startPos < imei_content.length());

// Then find the index of the last digit    
int endPos = startPos;
do
{
    if (!isdigit(imei_content.charAt(endPos))
        break;
}
while (++endPos < imei_content.length());

// Now startPos is the index of the first digit and endPos is
// the index of the last digit (actually 1 character past the last digit).
// Just take that substring and that is your IMEI number.    
String imei_num = imei_content.substring(startPos, endPos - 1);
```

Of course this assumes there are no other numbers in the string (there are none in your example).  If there are, you'll have to make your loops smarter and look for a string of 15 digits (or whatever length you expect).

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I had actually done something similar in the meantime, but extracting each digit then concatenating to a string rather than substring. Same issue as yours in that if there is a stray number it will be added in. Will try to think about how I could have it look for a 15 digit number to make it more robust, any suggestions? My code that I implemented since asking the question in next answer:

Answer (score 0):

Code I implemented in the meantime:

```
char imei_character;
String imei_content = "";
String scale_id;

void IsNumeric(String imei_content) {
    for(char i = 0; i < imei_content.length(); i++) {
        if (isDigit(imei_content.charAt(i))) {
//             Serial.print(imei_content.charAt(i));                       
             scale_id.concat(imei_content.charAt(i));                    
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but I am a little worried about it collecting stray numbers, I don't think there is any reason there would ever be any other numbers in the response to that AT command but just wondered if I should make it watertight?

An example that I would want to work around would look something like (or similar variation of) where "WS" is whitespace:

AT+CGSN

WS WS WS
23
WS WS
123456789012345
WS WS WS
OK

I would need several tests, it is easy enough to test if the string is 15 digits, what seems harder is determining which 15 digits to include if it ends up being 17 digits. Using the whitespace as a marker seems to be the key, something like if serialpeek = whitespace && stringlength() < 14 (sometimes the imei is 14 but usually 15) then discard and continue???

Will try to get my head around it.

this is what I have now. Seems to work - any suggestions welcomed!

```
String imei_content = "";
int startPos;
int endPos;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);

}

void loop() {


  extractNumber();

}


void extractNumber() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    imei_content = Serial.readString();
    delay(20);
    startPos = 0;
    do
    {
      if (isdigit(imei_content.charAt(startPos)))
        break;
    }

    while (++startPos < imei_content.length());

    if (startPos = 0) {
      endPos = startPos + 1;
    }
    else {
    endPos = startPos;
    }

    do
    {
      if (isWhitespace(imei_content.charAt(endPos)))
        break;
    }

    while (++endPos < imei_content.length());

    String scale_id = imei_content.substring(startPos, endPos);
    scale_id.trim();
    if (scale_id.length() <= 13) {
      verifyString();
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("extract number");
    Serial.println(scale_id);
    Serial.println(scale_id.length());
     delay(200);
     scale_id = "";


  }
}
}



void verifyString() {

  startPos = endPos;
  do
  {
    if (isdigit(imei_content.charAt(startPos)))
      break;
  }

  while (++startPos < imei_content.length());

  endPos = startPos;
  do
  {
    if (isWhitespace(imei_content.charAt(endPos)))
      break;
  }

  while (++endPos < imei_content.length());

  String scale_id = imei_content.substring(startPos, endPos);
  scale_id.trim();
  if (scale_id.length() <= 13) {
    verifyString();
  }
  else 
  {
    if (scale_id.length() >=14 && scale_id.length() <=15) {

    Serial.println("verify string");
    Serial.println(scale_id);
    delay(200);
    Serial.println(scale_id.length());
    scale_id = "";
    return;
    }
    else {
      if (scale_id.length() >= 16) {
      scale_id = "999";
      Serial.println(scale_id);
      }
    }
  }
}
```